# How to show all the legend of Qpie?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

How to show all the legend of Qpie?
The words will become....

how should I solve this?
[Program screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53KdC.jpg)

```
self.slice = self.series.slices()[1]
self.slice.setExploded()
self.slice.setLabelVisible()
self.slice.setPen(QPen(Qt.darkGreen, 2))
self.slice.setBrush(Qt.green)
#self.slice.setLabelBrush(labelBrush)
self.slice.setLabelFont(pieFont)

self.chart = QChart()
self.chart.addSeries(self.series)
self.chart.setTitle('History Data')
self.chart.legend().hide()
self.chart.createDefaultAxes()
self.chart.setFont(titleFont)
self.chart.setTitleFont(titleFont)
#self.chart.setBackgroundBrush(bgG)
#self.chart.setTitleBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))

self.chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)
self.chart.legend().setVisible(True)
self.chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
self._chart_view = QChartView(self.chart)
self._chart_view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
self.charWidget.setChart(self.chart)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph legend is not showing because the window width is small.

If you increase the screen width the subtitles will appear.

Note setFixedSize()

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtChart
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChartView, QChart
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQtChart Pie Chart")
        
        # without problem
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)

        # with problem
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)

        self.create_piechart()
        self.show()

    def create_piechart(self):
        # serie
        series = QtChart.QPieSeries()
        series.append("l011111111111", 80)
        series.append("l02", 70)
        series.append("l03", 50)
        series.append("l04", 40)
        series.append("l05", 30)
        series.append("l06", 80)
        series.append("l07", 70)
        series.append("l08", 50)
        series.append("l09", 40)
        series.append("l10", 30)


        #chart
        titleFont = QFont('Times', 28)
        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)
        chart.setTitle('History Data')
        chart.legend().hide()
        chart.setFont(titleFont)
        chart.setTitleFont(titleFont)
        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        chartview = QChartView(chart)
        chartview.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        #chartview.setChart(chart)
        self.setCentralWidget(chartview)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to make legend become two lines?

Comment: You get inline-organized legends with legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight).